# JMETER:- How to handle multiple CSV file if all files column name are same

Tags: jmeter

In Jemter:-  How to fetch the data from CSV file if we have multiple CSV files for all cases inside a thread(column name is same in all file only data is different), in my case , for all request data is getting from one file only (first case's CSV ) even though file name is different. and once i disable other request and run only single request it will take data from proper file.[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have dependent CSV files, i.e. trying to use variable from 1st CSV file as an input to 2nd CSV - it will not work.

As per [Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) chapter of JMeter User Manual:

```
0. Configuration elements
1. Pre-Processors
2. Timers
3. Sampler
4. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
5. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
6. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)
```

So being [Configuration Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) all the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) elements are initialized at the same time at the beginning of the test.

If your test configuration is highly dynamic and built on relationship of data from multiple CSV files you will have to go for [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) instead.

Check out [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime/) for more information on the concept and example solution.